# How to move unversioned items in TortoiseSVN to another location?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN has an option to delete Unrevisioned items.
I don't want to delete them, but instead want all unrevisioned items to be moved to someother location.
How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific command in TortoiseSVN to move all the unversioned files.
I suggest you two methods:

1. Use Copy and Paste with mouse through explorer
2. Use the following command line, which needs `grep` and `sed` commands (so that Cygwin or other bash commands interpreter is necessary on Windows):

   ```
   svn status | grep '^?[ \t]*.*\..*' | mv `sed 's/^?[ \t]*//'` destFolder/
   ```